# mongorestore -d mydatabase -c mycollections C:\Users\backup.bson.gz doesn't work

Tags: database, mongodb, robo3t, mongorestore

this is my first question here because i really don't know what to do.

So i got a Database named **mydatabase**.
I also got a Collection named **mycollection**.
And i got a Backup-File named **backup.bson.gz**.

I want to use a command in MongoDB / Robo 3T that restores the backup file onto the database.

Because of that i tried the mongorestore command but i get the error:

```
Error: Line 1: Unexpected identifier
```

I wrote the command as shown in the title.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use flag --drop

```
mongorestore -d mydatabase -c mycollections C:\Users\backup.bson.gz --drop
```